# Invoke a function using && instead of if statement

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have the following statement

```
 if (!this.customMsg) {
     this.customMsg = setInterval(() => {
         // doSomething();   
     }, 2000);
 }
```

I want to do something like this;

```
this.customMsg = !this.customMsg && setInterval(() => {
   // doSomething();   
}, 2000);
```

The above way doesn't work, what am i doing wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't work`? Does it show an error? Does it not do what you expect? Note that `&&` is short circuiting so if the first branch returns `false` it ignores the second one, since `false && true` and `false && false` would still evaluate to `false` in either case.

Comment: It executes the setInterval when condition is `false` as well.

Comment: Are you sure? It would do it if you call it three times 1. the first branch is falsey ->  flipped to true -> goes to the second branch and starts the interval. 2. first branch is truthy -> flipped to false -> *this.customMsg is now changed to that result* 3. first branch is false -> flipped to true -> another interval starts.

Comment: Never mind, I went with @brk's approach. :) Thanks anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this

```
this.customMsg || (this.customMsg = setInterval(function() {
}, 2000));
```

Comment: A more idiomatic usage would be `this.customMsg = this.customMsg || setInterval(function() { }, 2000));`